# If I screen-capture a snapshot from a HDR movie, will the snapshot image be a HDR image?

Tags: video-capture, vlc, hdr

I have a HDR movie content playing on a HDR supported PC, using software like the VLC layer. If I take a snapshot to get a png image file, will the image file include the HDR information? That is, if I compare the image file with the movie frame where it is snapshot side by side, will they look exactly the same?

Comment: Which software you are using to capture screenshot?

Comment: @Daman I am using the capture function from the VLC media player, while it is playing the HDR content.

Answer (score 0):

> If I take a snapshot to get a PNG image file, will the image file include the HDR information?

How do you take a snapshot? 10 bits minimum color depth of the PNG has the same effect on your HDR display.

Comment: I am using the snapshot function in VLC player, which produces png files with 24-bit color depth (8 bits for each color channel, I believe) on my PC. Does that suffice to produce the HDR effect?

Comment: Depends on whether the snapshot happens before or after down-sampling for your monitor. If the picture comes from the video file itself, I would think it would be; but if it's already been fit to your monitor and grabbed, I would expect it to be a regular non-HDR and post processed image, with values above one (for color brightness) smeared out. You might even try it once and use your preferred software to look at the color gamut of the final file, and see if it's [0-1] (standard) or HDR.